# pygtk drawing area not showing

Tags: python, pygtk, drawable

Hi guys I have the following code. I create an instanciation of this class in another file. This gives me a drawing area but the image as well as the points I have drawn are not showing. I am trying to write a board game. The drawing area here should contain the board

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class Board(gtk.DrawingArea):

def show_background(self, filepath):
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(filepath)
    self.get_window().draw_pixbuf(self.style.bg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL], pixbuf, 0,0, 0,0)


def __init__(self, parent_widget):
    self.parent_widget = parent_widget
    gtk.DrawingArea.__init__(self)
    self.parent_widget.pack_end(self, True, True, 10)
    self.show()
    self.gc = self.style.fg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
    self.show_background("image.png")
    x=20
    y=20
    points = [(x+10,y+10), (x+10,y), (x+40,y+30),(x+30,y+10), (x+50,y+10)]
    self.get_window().draw_points(self.gc, points)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950904/how-to-make-mini-example-for-drawingarea-display-something/15990158#15990158), but in your case, since you are using a class, you should override the default handler for the `expose-event` signal instead of connecting to that signal. For this you use a method with the magic name `do_expose_event`.

To summarize the other answer: You should only draw on a drawing area during an expose event, because anything you draw is erased again when the window is minimized or another window moves over it. However, the expose event always happens at the right time so you can redraw whenever it is needed.

Also, as I advised in the other answer, check out [drawing with Cairo](http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/drawing/).

```
class Board(gtk.DrawingArea):

    def show_background(self, filepath):
        pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(filepath)
        self.get_window().draw_pixbuf(self.style.bg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL], pixbuf, 0,0, 0,0)

    def do_expose_event(self, event):
        self.gc = self.style.fg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
        self.show_background("image.png")
        x=20
        y=20
        points = [(x+10,y+10), (x+10,y), (x+40,y+30),(x+30,y+10), (x+50,y+10)]
        self.get_window().draw_points(self.gc, points)

    def __init__(self, parent_widget):
        self.parent_widget = parent_widget
        gtk.DrawingArea.__init__(self)
        self.parent_widget.pack_end(self, True, True, 10)
        self.show()
```